# What are names like "net.minecraft.blocks" called?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I'm trying to find these types of names for certain Minecraft blocks to add them to a block whitelist for one of my mods. Is there an actual name for these? If not, how would I go about finding a list of or searching for them?

Comment: Folder names? It's www.mincraft.net backwards and instead of www it has the topic name. Are you asking what the style of naming is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are **java package namespaces**, based on the conventions for that language. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661698/java-com-package-namespace .

Namespaces are used to group together and scope different code components within a project.